# Привязать линию к элементам

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Подскажите, как реализовать подобную линию (оранжевую) в `WPF` приложении?
Линия должна быть привязана к блокам (их будет 3-4 и разного размера) и иметь цифру нумерации.
Пытался через `TreeView`, но подобное сделать не смог.

[image: Оранжевая линия]

Comment: Контрол свой писать придется.

Answer (score 2):

Ну если их будет всего 3-4, то можно сделать так:

```
    <Grid Margin="10,5" Grid.Row="3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="AliceBlue" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <!-- -<Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="0" Y2="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,25,0,-30" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="6" Stretch="Fill" /> -->
        <Ellipse Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Width="25" Margin="0,15,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Label Content="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,15,0,0" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"/>

        <Label Content="Блок 4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,15,0,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>        
    <Grid Margin="10,5" Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="AliceBlue" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="0" Y2="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,25,0,-35" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="6" Stretch="Fill" />
        <Ellipse Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Width="25" Margin="0,20,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Label Content="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,20,0,0" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"/>

        <Label Content="Блок 3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,15,0,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Margin="10,5" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="AliceBlue" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="0" Y2="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,25,0,-35" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="6" Stretch="Fill" />
        <Ellipse Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Width="25" Margin="0,20,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Label Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,20,0,0" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"/>

        <Label Content="Блок 2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,15,0,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Margin="10,5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="AliceBlue" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="0" Y2="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,25,0,-35" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="6" Stretch="Fill" />
        <Ellipse Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Width="25" Margin="0,20,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Label Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,20,0,0" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"/>

        <Label Content="Блок 1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,15,0,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

В итоге получится так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но это так себе метод, как мне кажется. Приходится начинать с нижнего блока ...

Comment: Ну для 3-4х неизменяемых блоков пойдет, а если это `ListView` какой-нибудь? Тут уже таким не обойдешься.

Comment: Если для списков, тогда надо свой компонент мастырить

Comment: Угу. Вот интересно было бы увидеть такое. Хотя это уже не тривиальное действо.

Comment: Я попытался реализовать ваш код в ``ListView`` элементе и вот, что у меня вышло [ссылка](http://pastie.org/10960592)    
К сожалению я не смог вывести линию на передний план, она почему то скрывается вечно за задним фоном. Также я не смог убрать линию у первого элемента и у последнего, я так предполагаю там нужно свойство ``AlternationCount``.